# Report Viewer exception

Tags: c#, reportviewer

How can I fix this exception in report viewer? It shows error when st parameters

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll Additional information: An error
>   occurred during local report processing.

Code:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();

ReportDataSource ds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dr);
f1.reportViewer1.Reset();
f1.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode =ProcessingMode.Local;
f1.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
f1.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "clint.rdlc";
ReportParameter pr = new ReportParameter ("clint", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
f1.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(pr);
f1.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Which code line throws the exception.

Comment: f1.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(pr);

Comment: hi @Islam Gx , does the answer works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `SelectedText` instead of `SelectedItem`.

**Before**

```
ReportParameter pr = new ReportParameter ("clint", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
f1.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(pr);
```

**After**

```
ReportParameter pr = new ReportParameter ("clint", comboBox1.SelectedText);
f1.reportViewer1.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { pr });
```

Comment: Islam Gx , i edited my answer , could you try it again?